# How to create a regex on bash to match a valid commit message?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm following [this posts](https://dev.to/florianbaba/a-githooks-example-and-how-to-share-it-with-the-team-42i0) about git hooks and in one example there is a regular expresion to check the commit message.

The message should be match `[XXX-123] My message` or `[hotfix] My message`

```sh
REGEX="^\[(hotfix|\w+\-[0-9]+)\]( \w+)+$"
```

But running the examples `"[hotfix] Fixing unit-tests"` and `"[PSBO-456] It's a valid one this time"` I get an error response from the bash script.

This is the script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Checking commit-message format..."

## the first arg is the path to the git commit temporary file
TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH=$1

## get commit-message from the temporary file
COMMIT_MSG=`head -n1 $TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH`

## init regex to match commit-message format
REGEX="^\[(hotfix|\w+\-[0-9]+)\]( \w+)+$"

## checking commit-message format
if ! [[ $COMMIT_MSG =~ $REGEX ]];then
    echo -e "Your commit-message format is not valid:\n$COMMIT_MSG\n"
    echo "Valid format examples:"
    echo "[PSBO-123] My commit message"
    echo "[hotfix] My commit message"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Well done! Your commit-message is valid."
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: `bash` regex doesn't support `\w`

Comment: Did it finally work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to support the `'` and `-` chars in your input string. Also, `\w` is non-standard in this environment, you should be relying on POSIX character classes rathert than Perl-like shorthand character classes. E.g. `\w` is `[[:alnum:]_]`, `\d` is `[[:digit:]]`, `\s` is `[[:space:]]`.

I'd advise:

```sh
REGEX='^\[(hotfix|[[:alnum:]_]+-[0-9]+)]([[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]_'"'"'-]+)+$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPr6we/1/) (just to show how it is working, do not use regex101 to test POSIX ERE patterns validity).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(hotfix|[[:alnum:]_]+-[0-9]+)`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `([[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]_'-]+)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[[:blank:]]+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `[[:alnum:]_'-]+` - one or more alphanumeric, `_`, `'` or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.